# PHP: Array_keys() with multiple search values?

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array with unix timestamp values like this:

```
Array ( 
[1552345200] => 2 
[1552431600] => 1 
[1552518000] => 1 
[1552604400] => 3 
[1552690800] => 3 
[1552777200] => 1 
[1552863600] => 2 
[1552950000] => 2 
[1553036400] => 4 
[1553122800] => 1 
)
```

it contains a date and how many time it's repeated, for example, the first one is repeated twice.

I need to obtain an array with dates that only have a repeat number (the number to the right of the unix timestap) greater than 1, it means that the final array will contains dates that repeat.

How could i do this?

Comment: if key > 1 store it in an another array , something like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Here's how you do it the simple way:

`$filtered = array_filter($arr, function($value, $key) 
{
    return $value > 1;
});`

More here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array and add elements with repeat > 1 to the new array.

```
$sortedArray = array();
foreach($array as $k => $v){
    if($v > 1){
        $sortedArray[$k] => $v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $timestamp => $repeats) {
    if ($repeats <= 1) {
       unset($array[$timestamp]);
       // delete false entries from array
    }

    // or you could

    if ($repeats > 1) {
        $result[$timestamp] = $repeats;
        //take right entries and put them in a new
    }
 }
```

there are plenty of options how to do so.

Comment: if you use `unset` for `$array` then this array will not useful on other location.

Comment: @devpro can you explain that further, I dont understand you right now

Comment: u are using unset for original array, this will overwrite this original array.

Comment: @devpro thats right. after the foreach the original array will be cleaned of unnecessary entries. thats the plan ... if you don't want any wrong/false entries in the foreach you use continue instead of unset